# c++ program crashes when adding new QGraphicsItem to scene

Tags: c++, qt

My c++ program crashes when i add new QGraphicsLineItem to a QList of QGraphicsPixmapItem.
Below is the function.

```
void MainWindow::linkComputerNodes(QList<Node*> routers)
{

    for(int i=0;i<routers.length();i++)
    {
       scene->addItem(new Link(routers.at(i),routers.at(i+1)));
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're iterating from `0` to `routers.length()`, and at the same time you're trying to access the element at index `i+1`, which will be out of range in the last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<routers.length();i++)
```

Goes through every single router in your list, but then you add a link from each router to the router directly after it. This means that for the last router, you are trying to add a link to one that doesn't exist. Try changing your loop to:

```
for(int i=0;i<routers.length() - 1;i++)
```

So that you only add links between existing routers.

Answer (score 0):

maybe off by one at routers.at(i+1)? i.e trying to access routers[routers.length]